# ActiveModel vs ActionView in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller, action

This is a noob question!

How can I save the model Action, once when I try to save in the controller, the params[:action] is taken by the action controller..

Here is my controller:

```
def viewTask()
  @id = params[:id]
  @task = Task.find(@id)
  @status = Status.find(@task.status_id)
  @actions = Action.where("task_id = #{@id}")
  @action = Action.new


  if params[:action]
    @action = Action.new(:message => params[:action], :task_id => @id)
    @action.save
  end
end
```

Here's my view:

```
<%= form_for :action do |a| %>
  <%= a.text_area :message, :cols => 10, :rows => 5 %>
  <%= a.submit 'ok', :class=> "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: Sorry, I have trouble understanding this:
How can a save for the model Action, once when a try to save in the controller, the params[:action] is token by the action controller..

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: How can i save for the model Action, once when i try to save in the controller, the params[:action]is already token by the action controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is more like a comment, but it is so hard to understand, what the question is about, so I decided to have this as an answer.

---

Come on, Fernando, how can we know what you're trying to do? What action should the form be submitted to? Can you show us your routes.rb, so we know, how the action form can submit to your controller action. Maybe, to avoid problems with naming conventions in rails, you should rename your `Action` Model and Controller to something like `Mission` or `Activity`.

What should your `params` Hash look like? Because there will always be a params[:action], that in case of a form normally is `create` or `update`.

Further, please try to use the built in rails methods, like:

```
# should be a POST method (am I right?)
# why do you call it viewTask?

def viewTask
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  # you'd better avoid extra DB-calls
  # @status = @task.status
  # @activities = @task.actions

  # you can load this with the @task-query by including or joining them
  # if you need the @status and @activities models you could do 
  # @task = Task.find(params[:id], :include => [:task, :activities]) 

  # if you only need the joined objects you should use
  @task = Task.find(params[:id], :joins => [:task, :activities]) 

  @activity = Activity.new

  if params[:activity]
    @activity = @task.activities.build(params[:activity])
    @activity.save
  end
end
```

In the code, I am assuming, that you're task model looks something like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many     :activities
  belongs_to   :status        # so it has a field called :status_id
  .....
end
```

Comment: sorry my poor explanations.. thanks i'll rename the model Action..  thanks

Comment: thx for correcting the code of my answer (bad, bad copy&paste):D Did all work out?